# iis 7 .aspx output cache - plain html output ? why?

Tags: iis-7, outputcache

i wanted to add output caching for all files on my site with iis7 to improve performance.
i followed the instruction ( [CONFIGURE IIS7 OUTPUT CACHING](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/710/configure-iis-7-output-caching/) )
to add kernel mode caching and i was suprised how easy it is.
but,
i guess i was happy too soon.
when asking for the page ( .aspx )
it seems like the css style is not applied for some reason, so i get an ugly page....

so i opened [FIDDLER](http://www.fiddler2.com/) to see whats happening,
and i see two 500 messages, one for the .js file, and one for the .css file.
the thing is, if i remove the output chaching, it all works fine.

any idea why this is happening ?

p.s
i have also tried adding .css .js to the caching , but with the same result.